# Facebook Share not grabbing meta-tagged Open Graph description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags, addthis

When clicking on my AddThis - Facebook share button it is not grabbing the `og:description` meta tag, but rather the `description` non-Open Graph meta tag as shown below:

```
<meta content="This is the description" name="description">

<meta property="og:description" content="<h3>Some Title</h3> Use this description">
```

And in the Facebook share dialog it's populated with `This is the description` 
Has anyone else encountered issues like this? I've seen similar issues when searching but I wasn't sure if anyone knew of a fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `og:description` comes before the actual `description` or better still, if you can, do this in your `addthis_toolbox` div

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" addthis:description="This is my new description">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
</div>
```